# Map concurrency with mutable keys

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, concurrency

***I have:*** `Map<K1, Map<K2, V>>`, where:

1. K1 is mutable. (It changes rarely and only in ine place, so I can just remove Map for K1 and set it again with another key)

***I want:*** Make map concurrent. I want concurrently:

1. Modify value (V) for K2
2. Replace the whole Map for K1

***UPDATED question:*** Is code below error prone?

```
public class V {
   K1 k1;
   K2 k2;

   final ConcurrentHashMap<K1, ConcurrentHashMap<K2, V>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<K1, ConcurrentHashMap<K2, V>> ();

   public void changeK1(V v, K1 newK) {        
      removeValue(v); //doesn't remove old val!
      v.k1 = newK; //PROBLEM: map is the same as before `removeValue` call, but it shouldn't!
      addValue(V); //doesn't add new val!
   }

   void addValue(V v) {
      if (map.get(v.k1) == null) {
         map.put(v.k1, new ConcurrentHashMap<K2, V>());
      }
      map.get(v.k1).put(v.k2, v);
   }

   void removeValue(V v) {
      ConcurrentHashMap<v.k2, v> subMap = map.get(v.k1);
      if (subMap != null) {
         subMap.remove(v.k2); //remove from subMap but doesn't remove  from map!
   }
}

  //also I can remove any value by K1 or K2 at any moment!
}
```

Comment: What should return `map.get(null)`?

Comment: @nachokk also a map of entities

Comment: Concurrency with nested mutable data structures is extremely hardto get right without lots of locks.

Comment: @SLaks I change  K1 only once: on user login. I hope I can allow that. As I said I just remove value with old key and add the same value with new key

Comment: does K1 'have' to be 'null'? (i.e. could you wrap access to your concurrent map, and substitute some private token object when null is passed in as a key?)

Comment: Also, note that mutability of keys in a `HashMap` is extremely dangerous. The position of the key object in the map isn't recalculated if the object changes.

Comment: (i) mutable keys are a bad idea, even more so in a concurrent structure (ii) replace null by a default `K1 NULL = new K1(someSpecificValue);`

Comment: @assylias yes, thanks `II` is a good idea. About `I` seems I have got no choice

Comment: @assylias look at updated question please.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis look at updated question please.

Comment: @nachokk look at updated question please.

Comment: @JVMATL look at updated question please.

Comment: @erickson excuse me, already corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is subject to a race condition.

Multiple threads can detect that `map.get(v.k1) == null`. Depending on the order of execution, one of these threads can assign a new submap for `k1` and clobber a submap to which other threads have already added their values.

One of the more prominent features of `ConcurrentMap` is its `putIfAbsent()` method.

```
map.putIfAbsent(v.k1, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
map.get(v.k1).put(v.k2, v);
```

Comment: look at `removeValue` method please. Why I can't remove values. Why I can't add them afterwards in `changeK1` method?

Comment: How do you know that you can't? What is your test to see if a value is removed, or if a value is changed?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk ?

Comment: execuse me for delay. I check it in debugger.

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk It works for me. You don't have anything to remove the submap if it is empty after removing a k2->value entry. Is that what is confusing you? If you need more help, post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that illustrates the problem. The current code in the question doesn't even compile.